# Calculate div max-height using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, document

I have a div that is, hypothetically sandwiched between many elements and is on the sidebar. I need to calculate how much space there is between the div and the element below it. And then set the max-height of my div to it's current height plus the space below, so that it never extends past that (thus extending the page). The initial max-height, will be a very small value, which should be changed by the JS. 
So, basically:

```
<thing></thing>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<another></another>
```

and I need something like (jQuery Example):

```
var spacebelow = space between mydiv and <another>    
var daheight = (currentheight + spacebelow); 
    $("#mydiv").attr("style", "max-height:" + daheight + "px");
```

is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I Think you want something like this :-

```
    var divoffset=$(#divID).offset();
    var divanotheroffset=$(#divanotherID).offset();
    var spacebelow =divanotheroffset.top-divoffset.top;
    var currentheight =$(#divID).height();
    var daheight = (currentheight + spacebelow); 
    //set the max-height:-
     $("#mydiv").attr("max-height",daheight );
```